# Parse.com starter project error on subscribeToChannelInBackground

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Already have another topic on the same issue, but that didn't worked for me.

Code:

```
PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in

    if succeeded {
        print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
    } else {
        print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
    }
}
```

And the error:

> Cannot invoke 'subscribeToChannelInBackground' with an argument list of type '(String, (Bool, NSError?) -> ())

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is it actual code you are using? Haven't you modified it in any way? Sometimes Xcode shows invalid error messages. Like you have error somewhere in your closure, but Xcode says that you are passing invalid params to outer function.

Comment: Thats exactly the code I have, the only thing that I did was setting my ApplicationID as on the quick start guide

Comment: What version of parse sdk are you using? It can be found in `PFConstants.h`: `#define PARSE_VERSION @"1.8.1"`

Answer (score 0):

I've just update Xcode for the latest beta version and it worked, but I still don't know what the problem was.